# C++, возникнет ли неопределенное поведение в следующем случае

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возникает ли в следующем случае неопределенное поведение:

```
void do_something(const Object& _1,
                  const Object& _2,
                        Object& _3)
{
    // ...

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ...; ++i)
    {
        const auto value = _1[i] + _2[i];
        _3[i] = value;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Object _1;
    Object _2;

    do_something(_1, _2, _1);

    return 0;
}
```

С одной стороны, здесь нет нарушения `Правила Строгих Псевдонимов`.

Но с другой стороны, внутри функции `do_something()` мы меняем состояние внешнего объекта, на который ссылается функция, как на константный.

Мой код ведет себя странно.

Причем, если я сделаю так:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Object _1;
    Object _2;
    Object _3;

    do_something(_1, _2, _3);

    return 0;
}
```

То проблема исчезает.

Comment: В смысле? Ведь внутри `do_something` меняется состояние объекта `_3`, на который функция ссылается как НЕ на константный.

Comment: Может быть, компилятор решит, что раз `_1` является константным, то он не может измениться, и можно выполнить некоторые оптимизации... Которые сломают код.

Comment: Если объект действительно константный, то не должен меняться. А компилятор имеет законное право применять любые оптимизации в рамках указанных в коде фактов.

Comment: А как ведет себя Ваш код?

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup, он ведет себя так, словно компилятор выкидывает содержимое объекта `_1`, заменяя его содержимым объекта `_2`.

Comment: *"Мой код ведет себя странно."* - так надо было привести этот "странный код". А то, что сейчас есть в вопросе, даже не собирается.

Comment: Здесь нет никакого UB. Вот если бы на ссылках стоял [`__restrict__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html), тогда другое дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если какой-то объект виден через константный путь доступа, это совсем не означает, что он не может меняться. Он может меняться через другие, неконстантные пути доступа. Именно это и происходит у вас в коде. Никакого неопределенного поведения в этом нет даже отдаленно.

Компилятор никогда не будет делать никаких оптимизаций на основе константности пути доступа, если у него нет стопроцентной уверенности в том, что объект не может поменяться через другие пути доступа. В языке С вы можете придать ему такую уверенность вручную, при помощи спецификатора `restrict`. В С++ такого спецификатора официально нет.

Зачем вы вынесли упоминание "правила строгих псевдонимов" в заголовок - не ясно тоже. Никакого отношения к "правилу строгих псевдонимов" данная ситуация не имеет.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь. Я предполагал, что данная ситуация может относиться к данному правилу.

Answer (score 2):

Если в коде  ваши обьекты верно инициализированы(в функции нет выхода за пределы последовательностей, то  не будет никакого неопределенного поведения. В данном случаи константными являются только аргументы функции, а передаваемые ей обьекты вполне могут быть неконстантными. Константность аргументов говорит о том, что функция не модифицирует первые два аргумента. Но третьим аргументом может выступать любой передаваемый неконстантный обьект, в том числе и один из двух переданных обьектов.

P.S. Вот какой код выполняется у вас:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Object a;
    Object b;       
    {
        const Object& _1 = a;
        const Object& _2 = b;
        Object& _3 = a;
        // ...

        for (size_t i = 0; i < ...; ++i)
        {
             const auto value = _1[i] + _2[i];
            _3[i] = value;
        }
    } //конец функции

    return 0;
}
```

обьект можно без проблем модифицировать через ссыльку `_3`

Comment: Я все равно не уверен, что `UB` не возникает.

Comment: может и вознинет, но только не из за сигнатуры функции, а по другой причине, которая не видна в вопросе